# Javascript object required error in IE

Tags: javascript, object, animation

i'm creating mulitple planet objects in javascript to handle animation.

The animation works fine for each planet but i am getting errors in IE 6/7 saying "object required on line 15 char 2"

Code:

```
var earthObj = null;
var mercObj = null;
var jupiObj = null;
var animate;
function init()
{
    mercObj = document.getElementById('mercury');
    earthObj = document.getElementById('earth');
    jupiObj = document.getElementById('jupiter');

    mercObj.style.position= 'relative';  
    mercObj.style.left = '54px'; 
    mercObj.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    earthObj.style.position= 'relative';  //error on this line
    earthObj.style.left = '80px'; 
    earthObj.style.top = 300px';
}
```

Comment: Maybe you missing earth?

Comment: Show us the markup, and where the `<script>` tag is.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to call an object, test if it exists.

```
earthObj = document.getElementById('earth');
if(!earthObj) {
  alert("Could not find Earth");
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on mac and don't have any IE to try. Do you get the same error, if you change the code like this:

```
function init() {
  var earthObj = null;
  var mercObj = null;
  var jupiObj = null;
  var animate;

  mercObj = document.getElementById('mercury');
  earthObj = document.getElementById('earth');
  jupiObj = document.getElementById('jupiter');

  mercObj.style.position= 'relative';  
  mercObj.style.left = '54px'; 
  mercObj.style.visibility = 'hidden';


  !earhtObj && alert("There is no element with id 'earth'");
  earthObj.style.left = '80px'; 
  earthObj.style.top = '300px';
  earthObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
}
```

I came accros [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368536/internet-explorer-says-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method) post and thought if the error might be connected with IE6/7 bug that triggers when some global variable gets the same name as dom object.

I also moved the `earthObj.style.position= 'relative';` to the end of block and expect the error to reaper at `earthObj.style.left = '80px';`

Comment: If not in `style.left` line, the error will pop up on `style.top` line on symbol 29. By all means :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that in IE, the function works if the script is after the defined/generated HTML elements.

i.e. place the script at the end of the HTML document, rather at the beginning, or use jquery's ready function:

```
$(function() {
   mercObj = document.getElementById('mercury');
});
```