# Angular 4 - new MouseEvent causes IE11 error

Tags: javascript, angular, mouseevent, internet-explorer-11, angular-cli

I have problem with mouseEvent in angular 4 on IE11. I am using angular 4, angular-cli.

When I activate this line of code:

```
let newEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseleave', {bubbles: true});
```

IE is throwing such exception in console:

> ```
> TypeError: Object does not support this operation.
>    at MenuItemComponent.prototype.onClick (./main.bundle.js:821:13)
>    at Anonymous function (Function code:37:9)
>    at handleEvent (./vendor.bundle.js:12039:87)
>    at callWithDebugContext (./vendor.bundle.js:13247:9)
>    at debugHandleEvent (./vendor.bundle.js:12835:5)
>    at dispatchEvent (./vendor.bundle.js:9014:5)
>    at Anonymous function (./vendor.bundle.js:9604:31)
>    at Anonymous function (./vendor.bundle.js:19253:9)
>    at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask (./polyfills.bundle.js:10732:13)
>    at onInvokeTask (./vendor.bundle.js:4357:21)
>    at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask (./polyfills.bundle.js:10732:13)
>    at Zone.prototype.runTask (./polyfills.bundle.js:10501:21)
>    at invoke (./polyfills.bundle.js:10796:21)
> ```

I uncommented everything in my polyfils.ts and rebuilded project, I have tried IE and ES6 shims...

I can not find anything similar in Google, and I think this is some silly issue - cloud somebody please point me to solution?

Comment: could it be this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368536/internet-explorer-says-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method

Comment: Nope, I do not have any id's on whole page. :)

Comment: Hi TZ, the answer I provided worked for me. If i helped you, mark it as an answer so that it can be helpful to others who are searching for a solution :)

Comment: Hey, this is so old thing that I can not reproduce it right now, but I thing Your answers are fine, so I will accept them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in `html` file:

```
<div #sample>You need to click me</div>
```

in component.js file:

```
@ViewChild('sample') sampleEle: ElementRef;
```

and the use the click event as in the `js` as:

```
this.sampleEle.nativeElement.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can trick for IE by:

import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

...

@ViewChild('fileInput') public fileInput: ElementRef;

...

```
// Trigger button click event
let event;
if (document.createEvent){
  // Only for IE and Firefox
  event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
  event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
} else {
  // For Chrome
  event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: false});
}
this.button.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```